# How to import audio files in mobile application

Tags: ios

I want to import audio files in my application from device and want to up this audio file to server please some body guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have tried so far....

Comment: You want to use iTunes song Library into your application?

Comment: Hemantwagh07 I don't know what should i do?

Comment: I tried to get the path of audio file and tried to get NSData from path. But I'm getting nothing.